# Прожектёрство, проект

Tags: этимология

Почему слово проект пишется без буквы "ж", тогда как прожектерство с "ж"?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что слово проект заимствовано в 18 веке из немецкого языка, в котором оно возникло на основе латинского "брошенный вперёд","набросок на будущее", а прожектёр - от слова прожектор, которое заимствовано из английского в 19 веке ( "бросающий вперёд", имеется в виду пучок света) тоже на основе латинского. Лат. j звучит как [ж]. Однако само слово прожект мы заимствовали из французского - "несерьёзный, ненужный проект" и от него прожектёр - тот, кто занимается ненужными проектами.

Так что Ж - это французское и латинское звучание, а без Ж - немецкое звучание.